# Add function after completion ((bool) -> void)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to call this function with a completion handler:

```
progressView.animate(fromAngle: 0, toAngle: 360, duration: 5, completion:
    print("go to next lvl")
)
```

However I get the error: print produces () not the expected contextual result type ((bool) -> Void)?

I do not know what this error means. I just want to execute a function when the duration is over in the completion handler. I already tried adding (Bool) -> Void in after the completion handler but this does not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corresponding closure of the signature `(Bool) -> Void)` is

```
{ (result) -> Void in ... }
```

So you have to write (redundant inferred syntax is omitted)

```
progressView.animate(fromAngle: 0, toAngle: 360, duration: 5, completion: { result in
    print("go to next lvl", result)
})
```

or with trailing closure syntax

```
progressView.animate(fromAngle: 0, toAngle: 360, duration: 5) { result in
    print("go to next lvl", result)
}
```

Why don't you use code completion to let Xcode offer you the proper syntax?